# Authentication error using Firebase Admin SDK with Python

Tags: python, firebase, sdk, admin

I'm trying to interface Firebase with the official Admin SDK for Python (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start).

However, I'm doing something wrong, as I'm not authorized somehow

This is my code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

# Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
cred = credentials.Certificate('./ServiceAccountKey.json')

# Initialize the app with a None auth variable, limiting the server's access
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://*[database name]*.firebaseio.com',
    'databaseAuthVariableOverride': None
})

# The app only has access to public data as defined in the Security Rules
ref = db.reference('/public_resource')
print(ref.get())
```

This is the error I get:

```
python3 firebase_test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 943, in request
    return super(_Client, self).request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 117, in request
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://*[database name]*.firebaseio.com/public_resource.json?auth_variable_override=null

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "firebase_test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(ref.get())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 222, in get
    return self._client.body('get', self._add_suffix(), params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 129, in body
    resp = self.request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 945, in request
    raise _Client.handle_rtdb_error(error)
firebase_admin.exceptions.UnauthenticatedError: Unauthorized request.
```

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 B with installed Python 3.6.

Can somebody point me into the right direction of why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Found it out!

Under database, go to rules and change it to:

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

It was automatically set to false after I've waited for a too long period since my last access.